# How to partly remove from strings in Array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I was wondering if there is any basic solution to remove the endings of all strings in an array?
I could do it with a foreach etc. but I'm looking for something somewhat smaller in code.

For example, converting this:

```
Array ( [0] => test1.csv [1] => test2.csv [2] => test3.csv )
```

To this:

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php

$arr = array ('test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv' );

array_walk($arr, function(&$val){
    $val = str_replace('.csv','',$val);
    return $val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php) which will remove extensions or unwanted characters from filenames.

```php
$files = ['test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv'];
$filesWithoutExt = array_map(function($e) { return basename($e, '.csv'); }, $files);

var_dump($filesWithoutExt);
```

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "test1"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "test2"
  [2] =>
  string(5) "test3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you :D

Answer (score 0):

Another `array_map` using [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to return the filename (`PATHINFO_FILENAME` basename without any extension):

```
$array = array_map(function($v) { return pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_FILENAME); }, $array);
```